# Python Excel Copy data without Formulas

Tags: python, excel, database, copy, copy-paste

I tried to copy and paste some data from 2 different excel workbook with Win32 but in the Target wb I always have the formulas of the Source. 
The code works but I only need the value.

```
wb0 = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathSource)
ws0 = wb0.Worksheets('wsSource')
wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathTarget)
ws2 = wb2.Worksheets('wsTarget')
ws2.Name = 'NB DATA'
ws0 = wb0.Worksheets('wsTarget')
ws0.Range(datacopied).Copy(ws2.Range(datacopied))
wb2.Save()
```

Comment: What is contained in the `datacopied` variable?

Comment: Yes it is! a range of cell based on a count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back on your previous questions, I see you asked this before and it had more example code in the question.

I think what you may be looking for is this:

```
wb0 = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathSource)
ws0 = wb0.Worksheets('wsSource')
wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(pathTarget)
ws2 = wb2.Worksheets('wsTarget')
ws2.Name = 'NB DATA'
ws0 = wb0.Worksheets('wsTarget')
# ws0.Range(datacopied).Copy(ws2.Range(datacopied))
ws2.Range(datacopied).Value = ws0.Range(datacopied).Value
wb2.Save()
```

Taking the value of the range, and not simply copying it's contents is what you want it sounds like.

EDIT: Keep in mind, this is assuming your `datacopied` variable is some kind of string that represents an excel cell range. I assumed this based on your previous question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is useful!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Can you pls help me with the library names?

Comment: If I remember correctly, this library is called pywin32. There are many examples on how it works with excel.